# How can I override !important on custom CSS on flex block wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I found this element of style and I need it to be `text-decoration: none!important;`
But it is not working on the CUSTOM CSS. Can anyone help me?

Thank you

```css
.element.style {}

.entry-content>*:not(.flex-block):not([class*="flo-"]) a:not(.wp-block-button__link),
.entry-content>a,
.flo-block-text__text>a {
  text-decoration: underline!important;
}
```

Adding screenshot to understand where should I go to edit the core CSS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syV6K.png)

Comment: As long as you're updates come after the snippet above in your cascade, you should be fine. If you don't see it working in WordPress, try clearing your cache. WordPress is a cache hog.

Comment: Also, if it's that critical of a fix, go into your core CSS for WordPress and remove the `!important` attribute. Then your override may work better.

Comment: Hi! Thank you @Millhorn I don't even know where to find the core CSS where this would. I clicked everywhere. I will try to add a screenshot. Thank you!

Comment: To add a little to the good solution from @Millhorn you should remove the !important to the other CSS code, and even change this code to avoid using !important. You might find your code connecting to your site FTP -> Your theme -> File style.css

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this in your custom css:

```css
body .entry-content>*:not(.flex-block):not([class*="flo-"]) a:not(.wp-block-button__link),
body .entry-content>a,
body .flo-block-text__text>a {
  text-decoration: underline!important;
}
```

Or adding some other class, id or element tag instead of "body".

Comment: hi, just did... nothing here. thank you!